# Brightness changing problem according to content in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, brightness

Brightness of my monitor automatically changes according to content of windows in Ubuntu 20.04. For example, when I go from black content to white one, It is brightening up to 100% slowly. Then, after a little wait, Its brightness is going down a little bit, approximately 95%. I adjust manually it and it goes again 100%. It is fixed in this ratio if I don't change the screen. But I have to change it to continue my works. It causes eye strain. It is really disturbing.

There are similar questions and solutions proposed. I tried those solutions such as changing bios power settings, editing 10-quirks.conf, installing brightness control applications but they didn't work.

Edit and Solution: I have found the solution. The problem stems from the monitor (Philips 226VLAB). When I close 'SmartContrast' feature of the monitor, the problem is solved.